# Find the $\sup\lbrace|e^{x/2} - P_{3,0}(x)|: -1 \le x \le 1 \rbrace$

Tags: calculus

We define $f(x)=e^{x/2}$

Firstly, I found the $P_{3,0}(x)=1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{8}x^2+\frac{1}{48}x^3$

**The question is how to find the $\sup\lbrace|e^{x/2}-P_{3,0}|:-1 \le x \le 1 \rbrace$**

What I did:

I consider that we have to estimate the $R_n(x)$ so that $\displaystyle|R_n(x)| \le \frac{x^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}*(n-1)!}$

The limit of the $\displaystyle\frac{x^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}*(n-1)!}$ is $0$, so $\lim R_n=0$

So the  $\sup\lbrace|e^{x/2}-P_{3,0}|: -1 \le x \le 1 \rbrace = 0$.

**More questions:**

1) I have chosen the $R_n(x)$. Is this correct ? Or I had to choose the $R_4(x)$ ?

2) Is the $\sup(...)$ result correct?

3) Have you got an alternative solution to this task?

Comment: The limit is zero, the supremum of the estimate would be found by maximising the $R_n(x)$ function, (hint, won't be zero!!). To do this, you might want to maximise $x^{n-1}$ over the interval you are looking at. ($[-1,1]$)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! So, I have to maximise the $\frac{x^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}*(n-1)!}$. But, how one can maximise a function that has an unknown variable n ?

Comment: treat $n$ as constant

Comment: So, the $sup$ might be defined w.r.t n. For example, $sup(...) = 1 / 2^{(n-1)}$

Comment: correct. It will be $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}$